# Pointing a Domain at another Domain and path

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7, dns

I was wondering anyone could enlighten me on how I would go about pointing a domain i.e. www.myfirstsite.com at another domain and path i.e. www.mysecondsite.com/firstsite.

I am wondering this is first possible at all (without some nastiness) and if so is it possible via IIS.

So www.myfirstsite.com >>> www.mysecondsite.com/firstsite without redirect if possible.

I appreciate any information

Comment: It is an IIS configuration issue and isn't (at least shouldn't) be about programming. See http://blog.pluralsight.com/iis7-redirect-windows-server-2008

Comment: I'm not sure this helps as I have the first domain in this case www.myfirstsite.com currently bound to the same site as the second domain www.mysecondsite.com. 

Instead of making another site and then redirecting I would like something that allows visiting www.myfirstsite.com to be the same as www.mysecondsite.com/firstsite.

So like pointing www.myfirstsite.com at www.mysecondsite.com/firstsite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven't found a 'clean' way of doing this.

So for now I am going to say the better way for doing this would be to set up www.myfirstsite.com as a seperate website and redirect anyone who hits www.mysecondsite.com/firstsite to www.myfirstsite.com.